# T-SQL Setting a scalar variable with the value of another scalar variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

Im creating a stored procedure that retrieves data to fill a radar chart. It worked pretty well using static tables und rows like this:

(This is just a piece of the code)

```
SELECT
   @aAvg = CAST(AVG(1. * foerderpy_1617) as DECIMAL(18,4)),
   @aMin = CAST(MIN(1. * foerderpy_1617) as DECIMAL(18,4)),
   @aMax = CAST(MAX(1. * foerderpy_1617) as DECIMAL(18,4))
FROM foerderpy a WHERE SUBSTRING(a.BSN,3,1) = 'g';
```

But now i want a dynamic sql. I want the stored procedure to always take the latest row of my table:

(These are just pieces of the code)

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @aAvg AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @aMin AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @aMax AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @tabname SYSNAME;
DECLARE @coluname SYSNAME;
DECLARE @counter INTEGER;

SET @tabname = 'foerderpy'

SET @counter = (
        SELECT MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION)
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tabname
        GROUP BY TABLE_NAME)

SET @coluname = (
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tabname AND
        ORDINAL_POSITION = @counter)

SET @aAvg = (SELECT CAST(AVG(1. * @coluname) as DECIMAL(18,4))FROM @tabname a WHERE SUBSTRING(a.BSN,3,1) = SUBSTRING(@restriction,3,1))
```

At the last line (the SET @aAvg), the stored procedure stops working and sql tells me "i have to declare @tabname", although i obv. declared it above. What is the problem im missing? Is it even possible to do what im trying?

The rest of the Code isn't causing any problems so i left it out. I need the @aAvg to calculate later in the procedure.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL.

Comment: You're supplying *values* (specifically, string values) in places where SQL wants *names*. Those are different things. As Gordon says dynamic SQL may be the way to go - although by the look of things, changing the data model is probably more warranted. Tables != Spreadsheets. You should be adding *rows* often. Columns, *rarely*. If you're adding new data by adding columns, that's probably the source of the complexity you're going to experience working with this data.

Comment: Something like this @Damien_The_Unbeliever ?

`SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @aAvg + ' CAST(AVG(1. * ' + @coluname2 + ' ) as DECIMAL(18,4))FROM ' + @tabname2 + ' a WHERE SUBSTRING(a.BSN,3,1) = SUBSTRING(''' + @restriction + ''',3,1)' 
  
EXEC @sqlCommand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your last query using [`EXECUTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) because `EXECUTE`:

> Executes a command string or character string within a Transact-SQL batch

So you have to change the last line of your procedure in a way that the query is written in a string and called by execute.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT CAST(AVG(1. * ' + @coluname + ') as DECIMAL(18,4))FROM '+ @tabname +' a WHERE SUBSTRING(a.BSN,3,1) = SUBSTRING('+@restriction+',3,1)';
EXECUTE(@sql);
```

If you would like to save the value in your variable `@aAvg`, you can use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with an `out` parameter, this way:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max) = 'SELECT CAST(AVG(1. * ' + @coluname + ') as DECIMAL(18,4))FROM '+ @tabname +' a WHERE SUBSTRING(a.BSN,3,1) = SUBSTRING('+@restriction+',3,1)';
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@aAvg decimal(18,4) out', @aAvg out
select @aAvg
```

Comment: If i have several scalar variables like `@aAvg`, lets say `@aMin @aMax` and so on. Can i use the `@sql`several times or do i have to use `@sql1, @sql2, ...`?

Comment: @sql is a variable, if you used it to run the query and don't need it for anything else (like saving the first query you ran), you may use it again.